# How to declare a listed variable in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I've created a function in solidity smart contract that add players in a game, the players should be stored as an "user" or a "hero" as a role in the game. The user send a transaction request while the hero send a reward. I've created a modifier to allow only the user to request and the hero to send a reward, but to define the role of each one of them in the registration phase I'm confused about it. Thanks in advance.

```
 function AddPlayer(string _name, string _role) public returns (bool){
 players[msg.sender].name=_name;
 players[msg.sender].Paddress=msg.sender;
 players[msg.sender].role = _role; 
 return true;
    }
 modifier onlyuser() {
    require(msg.sender == user, "Only user can call this method");
    _;}
modifier onlyheros() {
    require(msg.sender == hero, "Only hero can call this method");
    _;}

    
function Request() onlyuser external payable returns(bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    
    
function Reward() onlyhero external payable returns (bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    user.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare them as an enum. enum name {variable1, variable2}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping and functions to check user roles like that:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

// User address => Role of user
mapping(address => string) UserAuth;

// Set user role to a User Address
function setUser(address _userAddress, string memory _role) public {
    UserAuth[_userAddress] = _role;
}

//Check user role
modifier checkAuth(string memory _role){
    require(keccak256(abi.encode(UserAuth[msg.sender])) == keccak256(abi.encode(_role)));
    _;
}

//get user role
function getUserAuth(address _userAddress) public view returns ( string memory){
    return UserAuth[_userAddress];
}
```

and also you can set an *ADMIN* user as a constructor to control of the functions like that:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

// User address => Role of user
mapping(address => string) UserAuth;

constructor() public{
    UserAuth[msg.sender] = "ADMIN";
}

//Check user role
modifier checkAuth(string memory _role){
    require(keccak256(abi.encode(UserAuth[msg.sender])) == keccak256(abi.encode(_role)));
    _;
}

// Set User Role to a User Address
function setUser(address _userAddress, string memory _role) public checkAuth("ADMIN"){
    UserAuth[_userAddress] = _role;
}
 
// get user role 
function getUserAuth(address _userAddress) public view checkAuth("ADMIN") returns ( string memory){
    return UserAuth[_userAddress];
}
```